# Vue-cli - how to link local images

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have created vue app using vue-cli, I use vue dashboard to link libraries, one of them is Fake3D (https://luxdamore.github.io/vue-fake3d-image-effect/)

When I use external images it working fine, but when I use local images - it show blanks.

My code is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <fake3d-image-effect
        v-once
        centered
        fill-height-content
        image="src/assets/images/effects/3d.jpg"
        image-map="src/assets/images/effects/3dmap.jpg"
    >
    </fake3d-image-effect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    import '@luxdamore/vue-fake3d-image-effect/dist/Fake3dImageEffect.css';

    export default {
        name: "Effects3D",
    }
</script>
```

I got following error in console:

```
Unable to load image <img crossorigin=​"Anonymous" src=​"src/​assets/​images/​effects/3d.jpg">​
```

Folder `src` is in project root. How do I need link project images?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document for a detailed explanation on how to resolve static assets: 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

The problem is that when you write `src/assets/images/effects/3d.jpg`, Vuejs searches for the file in the root folder of your computer. It does not search it in the project's src folder.

See these 3 points for a better understanding: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules

- If your image is located outside the project, then, you'll use a static path.
- Since your image is located in the `src` folder, you could write `@/assets/images/effects/3d.png`. The `@` translates to `/src` folder if using vue-cli.
- If your image is somewhere else, then you should create a proper relative path using the `./` symbol to reach the file correctly.